# Is there any ruby library for usb hid interfaces?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, hid

I fear that there is no usb hid library, yet. Do anyone know good alternatives, which can be used together with ruby (e.g. jruby)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're prepared to stick with JRuby, you could try wrapping [javahidapi](http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/source/browse/src/com/codeminders/hidapplet/HidApplet.java). It uses the JNI to perform calls to the [HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the [ruby wrappers for libusb library](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?q=libusb) meet the requirements?

Also, this blogpost : [Working ruby HID listener example](http://hewner.com/2006/10/04/working-ruby-hid-listener-example/) has some code examples for interfacing with USB

Comment: No it doesn't meet the requirements because the libusb gem has no hid support. The example on that blogpost I already tried and it didn't work because of no hid methods/classes, although they're mentioned in that blogpost. But they doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've written a gem for reading HID controllers in Ruby on Linux (it's working directly with the Linux kernel drivers).

https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_hid

It's also pretty experimental right now, but it does work.

With it, you can set observers on buttons or control axes, which run on a separate thread, triggered by `start_listening`. This can set a value in a shared object, which you can use in your code.

Here's one of the examples, which just reports button pushes:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby_hid'

device = RubyHid::Device.new(
  RubyHid::Device.list[0]
)

buttons = RubyHid::Button::EVENTS

buttons.each do |code, name|
  button = RubyHid::Button.find_by_name(name)
  button.add_event(
    eval "lambda { |val| puts \"#{name} pushed: \#{val}\" }"
  )
end

device.start_watching

loop do
  sleep 1
end
```